# A PImpl helper class using type erasure

Tags: c++

This is possibly a duplicate of [Pimpl helper class](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/142774/pimpl-helper-class) but that's six years old, and takes a different approach, using `std::any` instead of `std::unique_ptr`. This has the advantage of reducing boilerplate at the point of use (at the cost of runtime type-erasure). The only thing that needs to go in the .cpp is

```
template <> FwdDecld<Foo> FwdDecld<Foo>::create() { return Foo{}; };
```

to produce the static member function used by the default constructor. And that's only if you want default construction.

```
#include <any>

// A class to make PImpl and similar easy:
template <typename T>
class FwdDecld {
    std::any m_impl;
    static FwdDecld makeEmpty();
    struct ThisAnyTag {};
    FwdDecld(ThisAnyTag, std::any impl) : m_impl(std::move(impl)) {}
    static FwdDecld create();

public:
    FwdDecld() : FwdDecld(create()) {}
    FwdDecld(const FwdDecld&) = default;
    FwdDecld(FwdDecld&&) noexcept = default;
    FwdDecld& operator=(const FwdDecld&) = default;
    FwdDecld& operator=(FwdDecld&&) noexcept = default;
    
    FwdDecld(T x) : m_impl(std::move(x)) {}

    // get():
    T& get()& { return std::any_cast<T&>(m_impl); }
    const T& get() const& { return std::any_cast<const T&>(m_impl); }
    T&& get() && { return std::move(std::any_cast<T&&>(std::move(m_impl))); }

    // operator*:
    T& operator*()& { return get(); }
    const T& operator*() const& { return get(); }
    T&& operator*() && { return std::move(*this).get(); }

    // Implicit conversion:
    operator T&()& { return get(); }
    operator const T&() const& { return get(); }
    operator T&&() && { return std::move(*this).get(); }

    // operator->
    T* operator->() { return &get(); }
    const T* operator->() const { return &get(); }
};
```

Then in `C.h` you can do

```
class Foo;

class C {
    FwdDecld<Foo> m_impl;
public:
    C() = default;
    int x() const;
    void set_x(int newX); 
};
```

and it will compile but not link. Then in `C.cpp`, you can do

```
struct Foo { int x = 42; };

template <> FwdDecld<Foo> FwdDecld<Foo>::create() { return Foo{}; };

int C::x() const { return m_impl->x; }

void C::set_x(int newX) { m_impl->x = newX; }
```

and it will link. The classic PImpl version with a `Foo* m_impl` would require several special member functions including `C::~C()` to be in the header and source, and each would provide opportunities to mess up value semantics.

There's a tiny bit more work if we want to have a fully private implementation, but not much: `D.h`:

```
class D {
    class Impl; // Forward-declare the implementation.
    friend FwdDecld<D::Impl>; // Let FwdDecld<D::Impl> see D::Impl.
    FwdDecld<Impl> m_impl;
public:
    D() = default;
    int x() const;
    void set_x(int newX); 
};
```

Then `D.cpp`:

```
class D::Impl {
    int x = 123;
    friend D; // This Impl class is all-private, so we need to let D see us.
};

template <> FwdDecld<D::Impl> FwdDecld<D::Impl>::create() { return D::Impl{}; };

int D::x() const { return m_impl->x; }

void D::set_x(int newX) { m_impl->x = newX; }
```

https://godbolt.org/z/aqjTaxhqo

Basically, rather than having client code (`C` and `D`) declare and then define all the special member functions, this leverages `std::any`'s type-erasure magic to generate those functions automatically when `create()` is defined.

This of course could be further simplified so that `FwdDecld<T>` only has a `T*` (or a `void*`) thereby avoiding `std::any` so that `sizeof(FwdDecld<T>) == sizeof(void*)`: Essentially the `unique_ptr` approach but with automatic generation of the special member functions which happens by type-erasure magic.

Also: Is there any way to make that `static FwdDecld create()` function just be the default constructor? That is, put `FwdDecld();` in the header and force the user to provide an implementation. I couldn't figure out a way.

Answer (score 1):

## Avoiding the need for `create()`

> Is there any way to make that `static FwdDecld create()` function just be the default constructor?

Yes:

```
template <typename T>
class FwdDecld {
    std::any m_impl;
    ...
public:
    FwdDecld() : m_impl(T{}) {}
    ...
};
```

Now the default constructor of `FwdDecld<T>` will initialize `m_impl` to a default-constructed `T` without needing a `create()` function. Of course, now the question is, what if you don't want a default `T` it, but initialize it with some values? You can make the constructor of `FwdDecld<T>` take a variable number of arguments and forward it to the constructor of `T`:

```
template <typename T>
class FwdDecld {
    std::any m_impl;
    ...
public:
    template<typename... Args>
    FwdDecld(Args&&... args): m_impl(T{std::forward<Args>(args)...}) {}
    ...
};
```

That, way you can do this in `C.h`:

```
class Foo;

class C {
    FwdDecld<Foo> m_impl = 123;
    ...
};
```

## Missing overloads

Did you know you can also have `const&&` qualification? And there's even `volatile`, so you need 8 overloads for a given member function if you want to cover all possibilities. In C++23 this problem will be solved by ["deducing `this`"](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p0847r6.html).